# Add weightings to Integer Linear Programming in Python / PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I have successfully used Integer Linear Programming to solve a slot filling problem using the following (+ some hard / soft constraints).

```
def opt(A, max=float('inf'),
                         min=0):
        """Find the optimal solution 
        M, N = len(A), len(A[0])

        # Create problem:
        prob = pulp.LpProblem("optimiser", pulp.LpMaximize)

        # Create variables:
        x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", itertools.product(range(M), range(N)),
                                  cat=pulp.LpBinary)

        # Constraints
```

Specifically I have a range of IDs (M) with an associated range of products (N), and products, despite initially being attached to multiple IDS can only be assigned to one ID at the end of the process. I am able to do this so far.

```
ID  Product
1   100
1   200
1   300
2   100
2   200
3   100
4   500
4   200
5   600
6   600
```

These are converted to the binary matrix in order to assign to up to 6 slots available (a min max of which I control with soft constraints), and this works fine as a basic optimizer, however I need to add some extra rules.

For example, I want to add weights to certain products (they each have an assigned score as a separate variable) and I need the highest scored products  prioritised to be added to the slots).

```
ID  Product Score
1   100     5
1   200     5
1   300     2
2   100     5
2   200     5
3   100     5
4   500     1
4   200     5
6   600     4
6   600     4
```

So I would want to prioritise those products that score 5, to be assigned to an ID first. Once all those are in, then the next descending score and so on.

So

1. Is this possible here and any ideas how to get there?
2. Could I add further weighting variables if need be?
3. If not possible with ILP - any other suggestions? (hope that's not O/T)

I'd really appreciate any help here..

Comment: I don't know the first objective, but you can add second objective term like score*selected product.

Comment: Are you able to share a minimum working example of what you have already? It should be relatively easy to add a secondary objective to maximise the included weights but I can't quite follow what the primary objective is.